# ASP.NET MVC Backslash is Removed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, backslash

In asp.net mvc razor I am saving a backslash through the textbox (ref. @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductDetailVM.ControlValue ). The value is getting saved properly into the database but when the form is opened in edit mode it removes the backslash however in the view source the values is perfect with the backslash. I tried a lot but could not make this work. I want to display the text as it is with the backslash in it. Can someone help?

Comment: Can you show your `Action`code please, because it seems to be working in **[this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1UOUcY)** fiddle

Comment: public ActionResult Detail(Guid AccessSystemId, Guid? StepId){
 ViewBag.Mode = 2; //Details
 ViewBag.AccessSystemId = AccessSystemId;
 return View("Detail", this.Get(AccessSystemId, StepId, Guid.Empty));
}